# flexbox container overflow auto is not working

Tags: html, css

**html**

```html
<div class="upcomeingEvents">
  <div class="eventContainer"></div>
  <div class="eventContainer"></div>

  ....
</div>
```

**css**

```css
.upcomeingEventS{
    display: flex;
    overflow: auto;
}
.eventContainer{
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 400px;
}
```

The above code is not working, the `.eventContainer` is floating over the entire screen.

You can see this here https://lms.bdevg.com/ below text `Upcomeing Events`.

The same thing is working in this pen https://codepen.io/ats99/pen/JjEzRyV?editors=1100

Comment: set max-width: 100% to fix this problem

Comment: `max-width:100%` is not working

Comment: If a container does not have any specified dimensions, how is the browser supposed to decide when it is overflowing?

Answer (score 3):

Use `flex-basis: 400px;` instead of `width: 400px;`.

Comment: It's working on desktop but not on mobile devices

Comment: Yes, because other components on your site are causing an overflow. This is a different problem.

Comment: No, i have checked by setting `display:none` for this component. If this component is removed then everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can just follow this code.

the children of `flex` display in `css` to figure example style on exit over of parent need to has `min-width` property. and parent should has `overfollow:scroll;`

css

```css
.upcomeingEventS{
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
.eventContainer{
    min-width: 400px;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-left: 10px;
}
```

html

```html
<div class="upcomeingEvents">
  <div class="eventContainer"></div>
  <div class="eventContainer"></div>

  ....
</div>
```

Comment: Please add an explanation.

Comment: No, it's not working. You can check it out here https://lms.bdevg.com/